# Giving error while running code for windows emulator WGA 512MB

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am trying out a trivial index.html file in the multi-device-hybrid-app in visual studio 2013. I could easily run it on android emulator. However, running on windows platform I ran into the following error.

```
cordova library for "wp8" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "wp8"
  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "wp8"
  Running command: C:\temp\projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\cordova\run.bat --nobuild --emulator
  Deploying to emulator ...
  ERROR: command failed in deploy.js : "C:\temp\projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\CordovaDeploy\CordovaDeploy\bin\Debug\CordovaDeploy.exe" "C:\temp\projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8" -d:1
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
at CordovaDeploy.DeployTool.GetDeviceAtIndex(Int32 index) in c:\temp\projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\CordovaDeploy\CordovaDeploy\Program.cs:line 124
at CordovaDeploy.DeployTool.Main(String[] args) in c:\temp\projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\CordovaDeploy\CordovaDeploy\Program.cs:line 208
  Command finished with error code 2: C:\temp\projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\cordova\run.bat --nobuild,--emulator
```

The interesting thing is that it also creates a new solution in the

> C:\temp\projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8

folder and if I open that solution, compile and run it, it just works fine on windows phone 8.1 emulator. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I have set the paths correctly in visual studio 2013 I believe!

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the error message it seems program failed to find any emulators at all for WP8. CPT2.0 used CordovaDeploy.exe to get the list of available WP8 emulators/devices which was buggy. It seems this issue was fixed in latest release of [Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova -- CPT3.0](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/cordova-vs.aspx). Follow the below steps to install CPT3.0

1. Uninstall Visual Studio Apache Cordova Multi-Device Hybrid App CPT2.0
2. Install Visual Update 4 from [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-visual-studio-2013-update)
3. Install CPT 3.0 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675)
4. Refer this for uninstall issue http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3014133